# Unable to start Spring boot Microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm creating a spring-boot starter application. The build is giving success but I'm unable to start the application it is stuck at a particular point and not moving forward not even throwing any error. I tried waiting for some time after running the app but nothing happened.
attaching ss for the same.

Also attaching my build.gradle

```
[![buildscript {
    dependencies{
//        classpath(libs.plugin.sphinx.gradle)
        classpath("com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:1.2.0")
    }
    ext {
//        jib_version = '2.7.1'
        gradle_git_version = '1.5.1'
        spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'
        spring_dependency_management_version = '1.0.11.RELEASE'
//        sphinx_version = '2.6.1'
//        sonar_qube_version = '2.8'
//        johnrengelman_processes = '0.5.0'
//        openapi_gradle_plugin = '1.3.0'
//        franzbecker_gradle_plugin = '4.0.0'
//        openapi_core_version = '1.4.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'jacoco'
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.gcloud.jib)
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.springframework.boot)
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.gradle.git.properties)
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.spring.dependencymgmt)
//    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.openapi.gen)
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.sonarqube)
    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.freeair.lombok)
//    alias(libs.plugins.plugin.kotlin.jvm)
}
/*
plugins.withType(JacocoPlugin) {
    tasks\["test"\].finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport'
}*/

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


/*jib {
    // specify the name of docker image to be built
    to.image = "eu.gcr.io/dmn01-rskctl-bld-01-2fd1/rsk/nfr-op-consumer-svc/nfr-op-consumer-svc"

    // specify the exact base image to be used.
    //eg: harbor.mgmt-bld.oncp.dev/mve_tools_rtl/sbs-java-wss-distroless:release_v0.8.0
//    from.image = "<key your base image>"
    from.image = "harbor.mgmt-bld.oncp.dev/base_images/distroless/java:nonroot_912dc0513659"
    container.user = "nonroot"
}*/

configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = "https://nexus.mgmt-bld.oncp.dev/repository/maven-public/"
    }
    maven {
        url = "https://nexus.sbs-bld.oncp.dev/repository/shared-services/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

def spring_cloud_version = 'Hoxton.SR12'
def gcp_cloud_version = '24.3.0'
def lombok_version = '1.18.26'
def spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'
def spring_cloud_gcp_version = "4.1.4"



dependencies {
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"

    implementation 'org.json:json:20220320'

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:${spring_boot_version}"
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.11.0')


    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.6') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${spring_cloud_version}"
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:${gcp_cloud_version}"
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${spring_cloud_gcp_version}"
    }
}

group = "com.lbg.dmn01.rsk"
version = "1.0.0"
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
//    dependsOn openApiGenerate
}

/*sphinx {
    sourceDirectory = "${projectDir}/documentation/source"
    outputDirectory = "${projectDir}/documentation/target"
}*/

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/package-name1/**, **/package-name2/**, **/ClassName1.java, **/ClassName2.java"
        property 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths', "$projectDir/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "$projectDir/build/test-results/test"
        //ignore listed rules
        property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria", "e1"
        //Local-Variable Type Inference should be used (Declare this local variable with "var" instead., )
        property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey", "java:S6212"
        property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey", "**/*"
    }
}

/*jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
}*/

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}][1]][1]
```

[image: Error images]

Comment: I don't know where do you get it from but the build configuration is wrong. If you are starting a new project then you can generate it here https://start.spring.io/

Comment: the problem looks like to be with ur logging configuration - please show ur logging config file (for example `logback.xml`)